# Laravel 4 memory error

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

The site I'm building using laravel 4 would randomly returns a 500 error on staging server either with the error page shown that a required file is missing or a blank page. No page of the site would load after the first time this error is noticed. Restarting apache fixes the issue. No file or database changes are made at the time the issue starts or during the apache restart. Clearing cache with artisan doesn't help. The staging server has 512MB RAM and 20GB of disc space. This started happening last week and is extremely hard to replicate or watch error logs for since it seems to be happening randomly every few days.

I would think that this issue should have nothing to do with database, assets or disc read because only restarting apache helps.

Are there any known issues with laravel or any of the vendors? Does anyone know a fix for this? All help is appreciated!

Comment: what is the actual error in the apache logs?

Comment: Fatal error: Interface 'Illuminate\Support\Contracts\ResponsePreparerInterface' not found in
/var/www/sites/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Application.php on line 28
 
The other one was identical but with another class in the Laravel framework (I believe Eloquent\Model).

Comment: try running composer update?

Comment: Yes, still doesn't help.

Comment: I'm guessing you're using APC and it's getting too full. Are you using APC?

Comment: Which version of php are you running?

Comment: Your laravel installation could be broken. Try re installing from source.

Comment: in the vendor folder, try deleting laravel. Then run a composer update

Comment: Agree with @AndriesMooij. Looks like PHP opcache issue. Try to disable APC or replace it with ZendOpCache.

Comment: I have had similar issues in the past.  Do you have any unit tests written?  If so, does the first request/controller test always fail?

Answer (score 0):

Empty your vendor folder, run composer update/install and restart your server.